# Pointer initialization in class initialization

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

Given

```
class Foo {
    public:
        bool *b;
        Foo();
};
Foo::Foo()
    :b()
{      
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
}
```

What does the `b()` do in the class initializer list? It seems to maybe initialize the pointer's value to 0.

Comment: It makes `b` be a null pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization); as the effect, built-in types will be [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization). That means `b` will be initialized to `0` (the [null pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Null_pointers)).

> 4) otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

and

> If T is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the integral constant zero explicitly converted to T.

and also

> Zero- and value-initialization also initialize pointers to their null values.